# Registering singledispatch function in dynamically imported modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to register additional functions from dynamically imported modules to a singledispatch function.

`main.py`

```
from importlib import import_module
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def handle(a):
    return 'default'

def import_something():
    other_module = import_module('dynimp')
    handle_result = handle(1)
    assert handle_result == 'int', f'Error: {handle_result}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import_something()
```

`dynimp.py`

```
from main import handle

@handle.register(int)
def handle_int(a):
    return 'int'
```

The assertion in `import_something` fails, I get `'default'`, not `'int'`.

I've investigated a bit further. The function object is somehow copied when imported in `dynimp`. If I set a breakpoint after `other_module = import_module('dynimp')`, `other_module.handle != handle` and while `other_module.registry` shows `handle_int` as registered, `handle.registry` does not.

A solution that works is to have a `register` function in `dynimp.py`, and pass it `handle`:

```
def do_register(handle_fn):
    handle_fn.register(int, handle_int)
```

and then add `other_module.do_register(handle)` in the `import_something` function.

My question is: what happens when we import a decorated function, and why doesn't this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `import main` creates a new instance of your main file. An easy way to confirm this is the following code:

```
>>> sys.modules['main'] == sys.modules['__main__']
False
```

One solution would be to change `from main import handle` to `from __main__ import handle`. (Note that this relies on the `main.py` file being the file that starts the program.) Another workaround would be to set `sys.modules['main'] = sys.modules['__main__']` before you import `dynimp`.